# Xamarin.Forms: Cannot get name and profile picture URL

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, facebook-android-sdk, xamarin.forms

I have the code from here:
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebook-sdk
and I used the method:

```
void GetMyInfo(string token)
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(token);
    string details= null ;
    try
    {
        fb.GetTaskAsync("me").ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)t.Result;
                details= string.Format("Your name is: {0} {1} and your Facebook profile Url is: {3}",
                                       (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"],
                                       (string)result["link"]);

            }
        });
    }
    catch(Java.Lang.Exception e)
    {
        string message = e.Message;
    }
}
```

but the `details` string is null. As I break and debug, it says that `ContinueWith` is Unknown Identifier, but no exception is caught. To token is there it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you wrote, I tried:

```
string result = t.Result.ToString();

Console.WriteLine("{0}", (string)result["first_name"]);
```

I hope it will help. 
Sincerely